# Использование DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

В некоторых случаях бывает очень полезно юзать DevTools в браузере, в моем случае это DevToos в Chrome. И при работе с ним у меня возник вопрос:
**Можно ли изменения сделанные в окне редактирования стилей, в DevToos сохранить в файле?**
Например: Чтобы изменения сделанные в этом окне...[image: Окно редактирования стилей]

...сохранялись в это
[image: Окно редактирования файла]

Comment: [Step 2: Save a CSS change to disk](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces/#css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Step 2: Save a CSS change ti disk](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/workspaces/#css) ,Спасибо 
[Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)